# Why is there a difference in the conclusions one can infer from the limit in the Ratio Test between Wikipedia and Stewart's Calculus?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Why is there a difference in the conclusions one can infer from $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big|$ in the Ratio Test between Wikipedia and Stewart's Calculus?

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test) is the Wikipedia entry on the test where we have that if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big|=L$, then the ratio test states:

- If $L<1$ then the series is absolutely convergent.
- If $L>1$ then the series is divergent.
- If $L=1$ or the limit $L$ doesn't exist, then the test is inconclusive and there exist both convergent and divergent series that satisfy this condition.

---

On the other hand, in Stewart's Calculus (7th Ed., Pg 734), the author states that if the $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big|=\infty$, then the series $\sum a_n$ diverges.

My question is why is there a difference in the conclusions in the case when the limit doesn't exist? Also, what is the example of a convergent series with $L=\infty$ that the Wiki article is talking about?

Comment: But if $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big|=\infty$ then the limit does exist, doesn't it?

Comment: @Pazzaz Oh, so that's the difference and I was incorrectly thinking that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \Big|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\Big|=\infty$ means the same thing as limit doesn't exist. Further, in the Wiki article, the second case $L>1$ covers $L=\infty$ also, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence $b_n$ "converges to $\infty$" if for all $x\in\mathbb R$ there exists an $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$ $b_n>x.$ I use the quote marks because by most definitions this is a divergent sequence (maybe should call it "diverges to $\infty$"?). It is definitely true that if $b_n = |a_{n+1}/a_n|$ has this property, then the series $\sum_n a_n $ is divergent, so the test isn't inconclusive in this case.

It is for the other forms of divergence, where the sequence oscillates indefinitely, that the test is inconclusive.